# Issues with a button to open new activity

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie if it comes to Java, so I took a part in a project at my university which was created to help freshman year with coding (like me :c). Well, I have a problem with opening a new activity from, let's say, main menu.

Debugging works fine, app launches but when I tap on the ImageButton "New game" in main menu, which in theory should open another activity in new .java file the app crashes. I asked my tutor (she's also a student) about it and she says that she has no idea what's wrong, because everything should work just fine.

Here is a part of main_activity.xml file of the ImageButton itself:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="178dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@id/start"
    android:src="@drawable/nowa"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hlTopBar"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="0.02"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import static com.example.wojciech.myapplication.R.id.start; 
import static com.example.wojciech.myapplication.R.layout.activity_main;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton przyciskStart;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);

    przyciskStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(start);
    przyciskStart.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View a){
    if(a.getId()== start) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nowa_gra.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

and nowa_gra.java

```
package com.example.wojciech.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import static com.example.wojciech.myapplication.R.layout.nowa1;

public class nowa_gra extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(nowa1);
}

}
```

There is an nowa1.xml file in layouts.

**So my question is, do you guys have any idea what's wrong?**

I really appreciate any help you guys can provide :)

Comment: Could you post the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors, the app just "stops working".

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/j9jBpiaE)

This is what Android Monitor in Android Studio says :c

Comment: looks like it's manifest's error. Add the 2nd activity to manifest

Comment: "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" This is a pretty clear hint about what you need to do to fix the problem.

Comment: Register your 2nd Activity in manifest file, and also perform the `onClick` check statement like `if(a.getId()== R.id.start)`

Comment: It works! Thank you guys!

Comment: When creating a layout make sure the application context is saved in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @RamithDR Since the OP uses a static import, `if (a.getId() == start)` works. In fact, if it didn't, there would be a compiler error, not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Register your activity in **manifest** if not registered.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Mainactivity.java to look like this

```
  import static com.example.wojciech.myapplication.R.id.start; 
  import static com.example.wojciech.myapplication.R.layout.activity_main;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton przyciskStart;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

addListenerOnImageButton();
}

public void addListenerOnImageButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    przyciskStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.start);

    przyciskStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, nowa_gra.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

Also register the new activity in you Android Manifiest.xml file for example;

```
    <activity
        android:name=".nowa_gra"
        android:label="nowa_gra"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score -1):

in your xml file replece `android:id="@id/start"` to `android:id="@+id/start"`res will work properly

Comment: While this change is probably necessary, it does not fix the exception.